# Calculating in radians the rotation of one point around another

Tags: c#, xna, game-engine, xna-4.0

I have been trying to get this problem resolved for week and have get to come to a solution. What I have is 2 points in a 2d space, what I need to resolve is what the rotation of one is around the other. With luck the attached diagram will help, what I need to be able to calculate is the rotational value of b around a.

[image]

I have found lots of stuff that points to finding the dot product etc but I am still searching for that golden solution :o(

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a game dev by any means, or even particularly good at maths, but I think if you translate so that a is the origin, it's just basic trig.

Comment: Are you assuming that a value of zero radians would have placed 'B' at the same y-value (and a larger x-value) of 'A'?

Comment: This may be more than you need, but since you talk about rotation (rather than angle) ... If you have a graphical object at B and want to rotate it around A what you have to do is translate everything to the origin, then rotate , then translate back again.

Comment: Hi all, firstly to answer TreDubZedd, it doesn't matter to me where 0 is. I basically have an onscreen object that for reasons I wont even attempt to explain doesn't know how much it has rotated. what it does know is its centre and another point (was at its base, but it will now be at its right) so it can use this method to rotate its sprite around its center accordingly, I cant run xna on this laptop as its a VM but WorkerThread's response seems to look about right in my test harness I cobbled together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Vector2 difference = pointB - pointA;

double rotationInRadians = Math.Atan2(difference.Y, difference.X);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2.aspx for reference.

Comment: Thank you so much, its amazing how simple these things are yet i have spent week misgoogling.

Answer (score 0):

A guess:

- 1.) Find the slope m of the line A, B.
- 2.) Convert slope to angle theta = arctan(m)
- 3.) Project the angle to a quadrant in a cartesian coordinate system centered at point A to get the normalized angle

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that due east (along the X axis, to the right) is zero radians, and that +x points to the right and +y points down.

The bearing of B with respect to A is

angle = Arctan2 [(A_y - B_y) / (B_x - A_x)]

Use the proper function to calculate the proper quadrant (probably `Math.Atan2`)

Comment: The standard arctan function doesn't properly work for all 360 degrees; you need to use the 2-argument `Atan2` version instead, as in WorkerThread's answer.

Comment: That's what the capital A was for (as in Arctan) but I'll change it.  I've seen it both ways.