# Finding a rotation around a point

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

I've managed to get a function working which will calculate and return the angle between one point and another. I've called it the `lookAt` function, because it's basically causing one transform to look at another one. Here it is:

```
this.lookAt = function(target) {
    var d = target.subtract(this.position)
    this.rotation = Math.atan2(d.y, d.x) + Math.PI/2;
    return this.rotation;
}
```

In this function's context, `this` refers to a surrounding object which has the variables `rotation` (a rotation in radians) and `position`, a `Vector2` class which has a few basic math functions and stores `x` and `y` values. `d` is a `Vector2` created by calling a helper function on the variable `target`, which subtracts one `Vector2` from another.

This works as expected--if I call this function on an object, the rotation correctly "looks at" the target. However, I'd like to know why I had to add `π / 2` (which is 1 radian, correct?). I got the original equation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684195/calculating-in-radians-the-rotation-of-one-point-around-another), but the answer did not add `π / 2` to the equation, whereas I have to.

Could somebody explain the math behind this? Also, I haven't gotten to that much trigonometry yet (besides what my Algebra course introduced me to), so please explain this as if you were talking to a very small child. :-)

Comment: `pi/2` is 1/2 a radian, by definition.  It's also 90 degrees...

Comment: Ah, okay, right. I had to look up radians on Wikipedia myself as I got impatient of waiting for my math course to introduce me to them (I'm still waiting!), so my understanding of them might be a little fuzzy. :)

Comment: Anyway, the answer to this question will lie entirely in the details of how you're using the result of this function.  This function (without the pi/2) simply computes the angle between a horizontal line and the line formed between the two objects.  With the pi/2, it's a vertical line instead.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well... what effect does adding the .5 radians have? I suppose it increases the angle between the horizontal line and the line formed between the two objects clockwise by 90°? *-edit-* You've answered my question. Thanks.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Also, if you post your comments as an answer, I'll accept it. Your explanation clarifies what's going on enough to the point where I have a hazy understanding of what's going on, which will have to do as some folks seem keen on closing my question.